# Google map markers not showing up when placed through listener event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

SPOILER ALERT:  I had a typo in my code.

---

The code below successfully displays the initial map with the initial marker at the latitude/longitude set.

I tried to add a listener to place a new marker when I click on the map, but nothing appears to happen.  I tried having an InfoWindow display on the marker, but since the marker wasn't displaying the InfoWindow showed in the upper-left corner.

I'm using `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js`:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.8590, -122.8158),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.8590, -122.8158),
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
    function placeMarker(location) {
        var subMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            postion: location,
            map: map,
        })
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `postion: location` in `new Marker(...)`, it should be `position`.

---

Original Answer:

1. You call function `placeMarker(event.latlng);` but there are should be two arguments: map and location as in definition. `function placeMarker(map, location) { ... }`,
2. `event.latlng` should be `event.latLng`.

One of possible solutions could be like this: 

`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
});`

You can see example in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments).

Comment: Sorry, that code was a mishmash of the various things I had tried.  I updated my question to the actual code I used (which fixes the errors you noticed) -- any other ideas?

Comment: You have `postion: location` in `new Marker(...)`, it should be `position`.

Comment: <facepalm/>  Thank you for spotting that, it was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `postion` should be `position` in the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.8590, -122.8158),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapProp);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.8590, -122.8158),
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    map: map,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

  function placeMarker(location) {
    var subMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```